# countdown timer for multiple events

Tags: jquery, arrays, countdown

I've created a very crude system where you ask a builder to complete a task and once that task is complete, the inventory is updated with the outcome of the task. My problem lies in assigning multiple tasks. If task B completes before task A, then task A gets the inventory update rather than task B. I've never played with setInterval and clearInterval so I'm not sure if my problem lies within how I set up a counter or how the inventory gets updated.

http://jsfiddle.net/jawa9000/KFgbj/

```
See jsfiddle page
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use jquery [Deferred Objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) to be able to set sequence of tasks.

For example, `$.ajax()` method returns deferred object which has `done()` property to which you can assign method to be executed when asynchronous call is completed

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help but I think I'll go with a solution based off this code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jmpcq/?editors=101

```
See link
```